# Animating a circle and a square

Tags: java, animation, geometry

I have just started learning Java programming, and I am stuck with an exercise where I have to make a circle grow and a square grow and shrink. There seem to be no error in my code, but the shapes won't resize at all. Can you tell me what I did wrong?

More info just in case: It is an exercise given by uni. We had to include a Shapes package in the external library.

```
public class Grow {

    private void animateStep() {
        Canvas.getCanvas().wait( 50 );       
    }

    private void eraseObject(Object erased) {
        Canvas.getCanvas().erase(erased);
    }

    public void animateGrowingCircle(){
        Circle c = new Circle();
        c.makeVisible();

      for(int i=0; i <= 300 ; i++){
        System.out.println("Size is " + i);

        animateStep();  
    }

      eraseObject(c);

    }

    public void animateGrowingThenShrinkingSquare(){
        Square s = new Square();
        s.makeVisible();

        for (int j=0; j <= 300; j++){
            System.out.println("The square is growing by " + j);

         animateStep();
        }

        for(int k=300; k >= 0; k--){
            System.out.println("The square is now shrinking by " + k);

            animateStep();
        }

        eraseObject(s);

    }
```

Below is the test class:

```
public class GrowTest {

public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {

    Grow g = new Grow();

    g.animateGrowingCircle();
    Thread.sleep(2000);

    g.animateGrowingThenShrinkingSquare();
    Thread.sleep(2000);
    System.exit(0);
    }
}
```

Thank you for your help.

Comment: `"There seem to be no error in my code"` -- if it's not working, then there's an error. As for myself, I find it much easier to find your error if you could create and post a valid [mcve].

Comment: I don't know how this graphics works, but after creating a circle I assume you would need to add it to the canvas with something along the lines of Canvas.getCanvas().add(c); Also, I don't think you ever tell the circle what its radius is or where it is on the screen.

Comment: Alright, sorry about that. I am new to this site, I'm learning. Um, it compiles without error  and runs properly. The loop goes through all the numbers. Even the circle and square appear, but they do not change size, which is confusing and frustrating. It is just a very simple program. As it goes through the loop, the circle is supposed to expand.